# How to increase the TeX open file limit?

Tags: external-files

I noticed that TeX has a open file limit, while using some additional bibliographies with [`multibib`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf), using `hyperref`, `backref`s and so on (basically only 5 additional `newcites` were possible in that document before hitting the limit).

I worked around that with migrating from `multibib` to [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), which I've discovered then and which seems like a good solution to other bibliography related challenges as well.

Anyways, I found this [2007 open file limit discussion](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2007-March/013313.html) and I wondered if the situation changed with current TeX Live distributions. And if yes, how to increase the open file limit in LaTeX now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've never experimented with changing it, but `texmf.cnf` has (near the end)

```
max_in_open = 15        % simultaneous input files and error insertions,
```

which you could paste into the local texmf.cnf and adjust. (On my system, the appropriate file to make changes to is `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf.cnf`.)

I guess you would have to rebuild your formats after doing this before the changes take effect. You might have issues with hard-coded limits in LaTeX that assume a maximum of 15 io streams; it's too late for me to check right now `:)`

Comment: @LaTeX allocation routines check for maximum number of files so you will definitely need to overwrite those counter limits as well.

Comment: Also, you'd probably run into trouble with the `\write18` weirdness.

Answer (score 12):

- LaTeX 3 (i.e., the expl3 package) has a "bitmap allocator" that only allocates streams if they are opened
- With LuaTeX you can use the standard Lua libraries, giving you an essentially unlimited number of open files

Comment: See also the `rvwrite` package (http://ctan.org/pkg/rvwrite). As far as I know, none of these solutions will help with existing code unless it is rewritten to take advantage of the facilities. (For example, in `expl3` we recommend storing material in a token list if possible, and only writing to file when required. The `expl3` implementation will re-allocate streams when they are closed, but this still requires that no-one tries to open more than 16 in one go.)

Comment: @Joseph From the looks of things, newfile is more similar in spirit than the expl3 approach than rvwrite. (My reading of the rvwrite docs implies that it uses a single file to write to for *everything*, and then splits it up later. I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 10):

The `morewrites` package (see [CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/morewrites)) aims to be a drop-in solution for the case of output files (i.e., just load the package early enough in your document).  It works by redefining some primitives.

Doing this for input streams is significantly harder, as emulating a primitive conditional is impossible, hence `\ifeof` would give incorrect results.  On the other hand, I have never yet seen a case of exceeding the input stream limit.

Answer (score 8):

In the [KOMA-Script](http://www.komascript.de)-bundle, Markus Kohm’s replacement for the standard LaTeX-classes and much more, he includes a package called `scrwfile`. The package is designed to provide a way around the limited number of file handles in LaTeX.

If you do not read German, the author has started the work on improving the [English manual](http://www.komascript.de/files/scrguien.pdf). He describes `scrwfile` on pages 258ff. You will find `KOMA-Script` at [CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script) and [BerliOS](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/koma-script3/).

Comment: anonymous edit converted to a comment: Additionally: Download the last package of the KOMA-bundle: http://developer.berlios.de/project/showfiles.php?group_id=4307

Extract the archive and search for the `scrwfile.sty`, as well as include the package as an individual package of your tex-project, e.g.: `\usepackage{./YourIndividualPackageFolder/scrwfile}`

For me, it worked without any great adoptions of my origin text file - also worked with *multibib* package;

Comment: This one corrected my problem, where morewrites fails with utf-8 files and rvwrite does nothing.

Comment: @Bjonnh I just saw that comment of yours.  Could you send me an example of a file where morewrites fails? (BL@gmail.com, where B -> blf and L -> latex)