# Using indexing packages with memoir

Tags: packages, memoir, indexing, subdividing

Friends, as you probably know, I have a quite complex document for cataloging songs. `:)`

As my normal workflow, I use the `book` document class with some dozens of packages loaded. I've been playing with `memoir` in other documents for a while and obtained very nice results. The idea of a "batteries-included" class is tempting and some of its features make much of my stuff very easy to achieve.

So everything was settled for migration, except for one thing: indices.

This particular document of mine requires several indices, up to 30. As we know, with a setting this crazy TeX can run out of registers in a blink of an eye. I've been using either `splitidx` or `imakeidx` to output the indices in only one big `.idx` file and then use the `splitindex` command line app to, well, split indices. `:)`

`memoir` has a built-in indexing support. As far as I went in the documentation, there's no mention of a limitation of number of indices, but it seems it's implied there, since we also define the index extension. I could not find any references on relying on an external indexing package, and [it's known](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51603/list-of-indexing-packages-pros-and-cons) that `imakeidx` is not compatible with `memoir`. Sob! **Edit:** From version 1.1 on, `imakeidx` now supports `memoir`, yay! `:)`

I beseech for your wisdom, o `memoir` power users: how can I use a indexing package with `memoir` or, if possible, make it provide support for 16+ indices? `:)`

**Edit:** Terribly sorry, I should've made a M(n)WE. `:)`

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeindex[aaa]
\makeindex[bbb]
\makeindex[ccc]
\makeindex[ddd]
\makeindex[eee]
\makeindex[fff]
\makeindex[ggg]
\makeindex[hhh]
\makeindex[iii]
\makeindex[jjj]
\makeindex[kkk]
\makeindex[lll]
\makeindex[mmm]
\makeindex[nnn]
\makeindex[ooo]
\makeindex[ppp]
\makeindex[qqq]
\makeindex[rrr]
\makeindex[sss]
\makeindex[ttt]
\makeindex[uuu]
\makeindex[vvv]
\makeindex[www]
\makeindex[xxx]
\makeindex[yyy]
\makeindex[zzz]

\begin{document}

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

which blows up the evil

```
Writing index file lll.idx 
! No room for a new \write .
\alloc@ ...else \errmessage {No room for a new #2}
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.49 \makeindex[mmm]

?
```

Comment: I couldn't see anything in the `memoir` manual to suggest there was a built-in limit. I think you define the index filenames, rather than extensions (all .idx). Of course, registers may be a problem, but "have you tried it"?

Comment: @Brent: I'm terribly sorry, I should have made a MWE, now added to the question. Sadly the registers blew up. `:(`

Comment: hmm, there IS a limit as the `\makeindex` open a new write each time it is used, and the number of simultaneous writes is limited. But the `idx` files are actually first populated at end document (AFAIR). But (again AFAIR) the `aux` is only executed once at the end of the document, so one would in any case need too many simultaneous writes. One solution might be to change some internals, write all index entries into the main `aux`, write a tool to extract these lines from the main `aux`, and then process those files. It is doable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 1.1 of `imakeidx`, just uploaded to CTAN allows to define as many indices as you want:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}[2012/05/09]

\makeindex[name=aaa]
\makeindex[name=bbb]
\makeindex[name=ccc]
\makeindex[name=ddd]
\makeindex[name=eee]
\makeindex[name=fff]
\makeindex[name=ggg]
\makeindex[name=hhh]
\makeindex[name=iii]
\makeindex[name=jjj]
\makeindex[name=kkk]
\makeindex[name=lll]
\makeindex[name=mmm]
\makeindex[name=nnn]
\makeindex[name=ooo]
\makeindex[name=ppp]
\makeindex[name=qqq]
\makeindex[name=rrr]
\makeindex[name=sss]
\makeindex[name=ttt]
\makeindex[name=uuu]
\makeindex[name=vvv]
\makeindex[name=www]
\makeindex[name=xxx]
\makeindex[name=yyy]
\makeindex[name=zzz]

\begin{document}

Hello world.

\index[aaa]{A}
\index[bbb]{B}
\index[ccc]{C}
\index[ddd]{D}
\index[eee]{E}
\index[fff]{F}
\index[ggg]{G}
\index[hhh]{H}
\index[iii]{I}
\index[jjj]{J}
\index[kkk]{K}
\index[lll]{L}
\index[mmm]{M}
\index[nnn]{N}
\index[ooo]{O}
\index[ppp]{P}
\index[qqq]{Q}
\index[rrr]{R}
\index[sss]{S}
\index[ttt]{T}
\index[uuu]{U}
\index[vvv]{V}
\index[www]{W}
\index[xxx]{X}
\index[yyy]{Y}
\index[zzz]{Z}


\printindex[aaa]
\printindex[bbb]
\printindex[ccc]
\printindex[ddd]
\printindex[eee]
\printindex[fff]
\printindex[ggg]
\printindex[hhh]
\printindex[iii]
\printindex[jjj]
\printindex[kkk]
\printindex[lll]
\printindex[mmm]
\printindex[nnn]
\printindex[ooo]
\printindex[ppp]
\printindex[qqq]
\printindex[rrr]
\printindex[sss]
\printindex[ttt]
\printindex[uuu]
\printindex[vvv]
\printindex[www]
\printindex[xxx]
\printindex[yyy]
\printindex[zzz]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! A tear of joy just fell off my eyes. Grazie mille, egreg! `:)`

Answer (score 7):

This is in fact the first time I've used memoir so this isn't exactly tested but this appears to work.

Arrange that all the index entries get written to the same `.idx` file but using variant `\indexentry` commands.

Run makeindex once for each desired index outputting to the separate `.ind` files each time specifying the appropriate keyword to use for that index (ignore the warnings about all the other index entries)

The printing of the indices is unaffected as any number of `.ind` files can be input.

so: `id1.tex`

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeindex}[1][\jobname]{%
  \if@filesw
    \def\index{\@bsphack%
      \@ifnextchar [{\@index}{\@index[\jobname]}}
    \def\specialindex{\@bsphack\@spindex}%
    \expandafter\let\csname #1@idxfile\endcsname\@empty
    \makememindexhook
  \mkindexonce
  \fi}

\def\mkindexonce{%
    \expandafter\newwrite\csname \jobname @idxfile\endcsname
    \expandafter\immediate\openout \csname \jobname @idxfile\endcsname \jobname.idx\relax
    \typeout{Writing index file \jobname.idx }%
    \let\mkindexonce\relax}

\renewcommand{\@@wrindexm@m}[1]{\begingroup
  \def\@idxfile{\@nameuse{#1@idxfile}}%
  \def\@idxfil@{#1}%
  \@sanitize
  \@@@wrindexm@m}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\@@@wrindexm@m#1#2{%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\write\csname \jobname @idxfile\endcsname{\string\indexentry\@idxfil@{#1}{#2}}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}%
}


\makeatother
\makeindex[aaa]
\makeindex[bbb]
\makeindex[ccc]
\makeindex[ddd]
\makeindex[eee]
\makeindex[fff]
\makeindex[ggg]
\makeindex[hhh]
\makeindex[iii]
\makeindex[jjj]
\makeindex[kkk]
\makeindex[lll]
\makeindex[mmm]
\makeindex[nnn]
\makeindex[ooo]
\makeindex[ppp]
\makeindex[qqq]
\makeindex[rrr]
\makeindex[sss]
\makeindex[ttt]
\makeindex[uuu]
\makeindex[vvv]
\makeindex[www]
\makeindex[xxx]
\makeindex[yyy]
\makeindex[zzz]

%
\begin{document}
\makeatletter


Hello world.\index[aaa]{one}\index[bbb]{tkwo}

\printindex[aaa]
\printindex[bbb]
\end{document}
```

If you process that you get a `id1.idx` that looks like:

```
\indexentryaaa{one}{1}
\indexentrybbb{tkwo}{1}
```

so now you need

`aaa.is`

```
 keyword "\\indexentryaaa"
```

and

`bbb.is`

```
keyword "\\indexentrybbb"
```

then you can produce the two separate indices with

```
makeindex -s aaa.is  -o aaa.ind id1
makeindex -s bbb.is  -o bbb.ind id1
```

which produces

`aaa.ind`

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item one, 1

\end{theindex}
```

and

`bbb.ind`

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item tkwo, 1

\end{theindex}
```

which get input at the end. As is they bot get the heading "The Index" but you could change that in either the tex (redefining `theindex`) or in the makeindex styles (writing a different prefix than the default `\begin{theindex}` or presumably since memoir supports multiple indices it has a better way of setting the headings:-)

Comment: Wow, David! This answer is superb. `:)` Thank you very much for teaching me the ways of the TeX force! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not a direct answer to your question, but a work-around: I suggest you try Markus Kohm’s `scrwfile`. The package is design to provide a way around the limited number of file handles in LaTeX. It is included in his excellent [KOMA-Script-bundle](http://www.komascript.de).

The author has started the work on improving the [English manual](http://www.komascript.de/files/scrguien.pdf). He describes `scrwfile` on pages 259ff. You will find `KOMA-Script` at [CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script) and [BerliOS](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/koma-script3/).

Also, have a look at the other answers to the [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6091/9632) some weeks ago:

Comment: Small mistake: www,komascript.de instead of www.komascript.de

Comment: Thank you very much for mentioning `KOMA-Script`. `:)` I'm eager to try it too, as it seems as powerful as `memoir`. Also, the `morewrites` package from Bruno Le Floch seems also to solve the index issue. Thanks!