# 15 nested graphs cause "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=15]"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a diagram that has more than 15 nested graph, but i have this error :

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=15].
l.2 ...rfaceToDisplay.resumeGraphDrawingCoroutine()}

l.94 \end{tikzpicture}

17938 words of node memory still in use:
539 hlist, 28 vlist, 29 rule, 2386 glue, 14 kern, 15 penalty, 62 glyph, 
113 glue_spec, 3 temp, 1 write, 14 local_par, 4 dir, 516 pdf_literal, 
33 pdf_refximage, 57 pdf_colorstack nodes avail lists:   
1:7,2:26,3:11,4:11,5:1,6:7,7:2,9:8
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on netwworkmap.log.enter code here
```

I use lualatex and pgf 3.0.0. Here is an exemple tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [layered layout, grow=right, level distance=5cm, sibling sep=.5em, sibling distance=1cm, subgraph nodes={red, draw}]

    \node [label=center:Internet] (internet) {\includegraphics{cloud}};
    \node [label=above:router] (router) {\includegraphics{router}};

    \node [label=above:switch 1] (switch1) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 10] (pc10) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 2] (switch2) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 20] (pc20) {\includegraphics{pc}};
    \node [label=above:pc 21] (pc21) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 3] (switch3) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 30] (pc30) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 4] (switch4) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 40] (pc40) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 5] (switch5) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 50] (pc50) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 6] (switch6) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 60] (pc60) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 7] (switch7) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 70] (pc70) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 8] (switch8) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 80] (pc80) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 9] (switch9) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 90] (pc90) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 10] (switch10) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 100] (pc100) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 11] (switch11) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 110] (pc110) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 12] (switch12) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 120] (pc120) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 13] (switch13) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 130] (pc130) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 14] (switch14) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 140] (pc140) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \node [label=above:switch 15] (switch15) {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};
    \node [label=above:pc 150] (pc150) {\includegraphics{pc}};

    \graph [use existing nodes] {
        internet -- router;
        router -- switch1;
        router -- switch2;
        router -- switch3;
        router -- switch4;
        router -- switch5;
        router -- switch6;
        router -- switch7;
        router -- switch8;
        router -- switch9;
        router -- switch10;
        router -- switch11;
        router -- switch12;
        router -- switch13;
        router -- switch14;
        router -- switch15;
        Lab 1 // [tree layout] {switch1; pc10; switch1 -- pc10;};
        Lab 2 // [tree layout] {switch2; pc20; pc21; switch2 -- pc20; switch2 -- pc21;};
        Lab 3 // [tree layout] {switch3; pc30; switch3 -- pc30;};
        Lab 4 // [tree layout] {switch4; pc40; switch4 -- pc40;};
        Lab 5 // [tree layout] {switch5; pc50; switch5 -- pc50;};
        Lab 6 // [tree layout] {switch6; pc60; switch6 -- pc60;};
        Lab 7 // [tree layout] {switch7; pc70; switch7 -- pc70;};
        Lab 8 // [tree layout] {switch8; pc80; switch8 -- pc80;};
        Lab 9 // [tree layout] {switch9; pc90; switch9 -- pc90;};
        Lab 10 // [tree layout] {switch10; pc100; switch10 -- pc100;};
        Lab 11 // [tree layout] {switch11; pc110; switch11 -- pc110;};
        Lab 12 // [tree layout] {switch12; pc120; switch12 -- pc120;};
        Lab 13 // [tree layout] {switch13; pc130; switch13 -- pc130;};
        Lab 14 // [tree layout] {switch14; pc140; switch14 -- pc140;};
        Lab 15 // [tree layout] {switch15; pc150; switch15 -- pc150;};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I do to pass this limit?

thanks

Comment: It works with miktex (even if I use the files from the texlive texmf-dist-tree) but not with texlive2014. The problem in texlive seems to be the setting `max_in_open = 15` in texmf.cnf. If I change this to `max_in_open = 30` your example works. But I have some doubts that it is safe to do this generally (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6091/how-to-increase-the-tex-open-file-limit) and I don't if and how you could restrict such a change to luatex (and if it is safe there ...).

Comment: Addition: miktex sets max_in_open to 50 (http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/texdefaults.html). So it looks as if a larger value doesn't harm. But you could ask on the texlive list for a confirmation.

Comment: The comments in the answer referenced by @UlrikeFischer are misleading. The limit on 16 streams open for `\read` is fixed in the syntax of TeX and not expandable the limit here applies (as well) to \input and is changeable as a system limit without implying changes are needed to the latex read allocation system.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I already suspected this as miktex seems to work fine with a value of 50 but thanks for the confirmation. Did I got it right that max_in_open if for "nested" inputs, when an input file inputs another which inputs another? I never thought about it but now I wonder how tex handles it without opening a new read stream for each file. Does it keep the outer file in memory?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it opens streams at the operating system level (up to the limit here) but only a subset of those are exposed to `\read` which is limited to 16 just by the syntax rules of tex.

Comment: thanks @UlrikeFischer and @DavidCarlisle. I put `max_in_open = 30` in `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/00debian.cnf` and run `sudo update-texmf` and works very well for me.